# An existence of global solution of differential equation of first order

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: (a,b) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^1$ in $D:=(a,b) \times \mathbb{R}$ and satisfies condition $$| f(t,x)| \leq A+B|x|  \textrm{ for }  (t,x) \in D,$$ where $A,B$ are fixed real constants and let $t_0 \in (a,b)$.

How to prove using the fixed point method that for arbitrary $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ there exist exactly one solution $x: (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x) $$ with condition $x(t_0)=x_0$ ?

Thanks.

Added.

Maybe it would be. Let $X=\{x:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: \sup_{t\in (a,b)}  e^{-B\gamma|t-t_0|} |x(t)|   <\infty, x(t_0)=x_0 \}$,
$d(x,y)=\sup_{t\in (a,b)} e^{-B\gamma|t-t_0|} |x(t)-y(t)|$ for $x,y \in X$, where $\gamma$ is a suitable positive constant.
Then $(X,d)$ is a complete metric  space and $Tx(t):=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s))ds$, for $x \in X$ and $t\in (a,b)$, maps X into itself
(because  $|f(s,x(s))|\leq A+Be^{B\gamma|t-t_0|}\cdot sup_{t\in (a,b)} |x(s)|e^{-B\gamma|t-t_0|} |x(t)|$ and      $| \int_{t_0}^t e^{B \gamma |s-t_0|} ds| \leq \frac{1}{B \gamma} e^{B\gamma|t-t_0|}$).
However I don't know is it $T$ a contraction with some $\gamma>0$ and whether or not each solution of the differential equation belongs to $X$.

Comment: On first glance this looks like a candidate for the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem).

Comment: I agree. I suppose that it could be done by taking operator $Tx(t)=x_0+\int_{x_0}^t f(s,x(s))ds$ for $x\in X$ and $t\in(a,b)$, where $X$ is the space continuous functions such that $sup_{t\in (a,b)} |x(t)| e^{-L|t-t_0|}< \infty$ and $x(t_0)=x_0$ with Bielecki's norm $\|x\|=sup_{t\in (a,b)} |x(t)| e^{-L|t-t_0|}$, where $L$ is Lipschitz constant for $f$.

Comment: @Richard: if $x_0\neq 0$, $X$ is not a vector space, and $f$ may not be Lipschitz continuous, for example with $f(t,x)=\sin (x^2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Picard-Lindelof theorem there is a unique local solution, and it is global if you can show that the solution does not blow up. The latter is easy to show by using the given bound on f.

Namely, we have
$$
\frac12\frac{dx^2}{dt}=xf(x,t)\leq |x|(A+B|x|)\leq A+(A+B)x^2,
$$
giving an exponential bound on $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But could you write more detaily why a local solution can be extended to global one on $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Richard: I updated the answer.

Comment: Very thanks for help.

Comment: @timur Can you explain why your last inequality is true in the last display? I mean how to upper bound $|x|(A+B|x|)$?

Comment: @Hermi It was a long time ago but I think it is just the bound $|x|\leq1+x^2$.