# Show an ODE has a global solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show the following ODEs have global solution?

1. $x''+x+x^3=0$
2. $x''+x'+x+x^3=0$
3. $\begin{cases}x'=4xy^3+2x\\
         y'=-4x^3-2y-\cos(x)\end{cases}$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/an-existence-of-global-solution-of-differential-equation-of-first-order).

Comment: @Olivia: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem that you can share? What are you currently studying? Can you provide any details? Are you familiar with linearization? Are you familiar with potential functions? Are you familiar with the Picard–Lindelöf theorem? Posting three problems like this makes it difficult to provide appropriate guidance. Regards

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No,  not really. We do not have a linear bound here.

Answer (score 2):

Intuition from physics often helps with ODE. The first problem describes a 1D particle subject to the force $-x-x^3$ (assuming unit mass of the particle). The force is conservative (as are all 1D forces that depend only on position). Its potential function is $U(x)=x^2/2+x^4/4$. Therefore,  the total energy 
$$\frac12 (x')^2+U(x) \tag1$$
should be constant in time. Which you can check just by differentiating (1) in $t$; this does not rely on any facts from physics. Once you know that $x$ and $x'$ are uniformly bounded, the  Picard–Lindelöf theorem gives you an interval of existence of uniform size, which implies global existence.

Problem 2 differs from 1  only by $x'$, which in physical terms means dissipative force $-x'$. Now the function (1) will be decreasing in time instead of being constant. This again implies  that $x$ and $x'$ are uniformly bounded, and the rest goes as in 1.

I don't see an easy approach to the last problem -- are you sure it's stated correctly? In any case, [two out of three ain't bad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5hWWe-ts2s).