# Using contraction mapping theorem to prove existence/uniqueness of solutions of Linear first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In class we used the contraction mapping theorem to prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions to a first order (not necessarily linear) ODE on some interval [0,h].

The method we used was this: First convert the linear ODE into an integral equation of the form $u=f(t)+\int_0^s k(t,s)g(t,u(s)) \ ds$. and define an operator $Tu=f(t)+\int_0^s k(t,s)g(t,u(s)) \ ds$. Then use the contraction mapping theorem to ensure $T$ has a fixed point (and thus the integral equation is uniquely solved) on some small enough interval $[0,h]$.

My question is this:

Suppose I restrict the ODE to be a linear ODE only. That is, the operator is now 
$T=f(t)+\int_0^s k(t,s)u(s) \ ds$. The above contraction mapping still gives us a unique solution on $[0,h]$. Using this fact, how can I show that there is a unique solution for $[h,2h]$ and, therefore, for all intervals $[0,k]$?

Comment: one way to do it, is to show that there is a fixed point in $[h,2h]$ and so on. Then by continuity conditons, these fixed points, define a unique smooth function, the solution

Comment: @NikosM. why is linearity necessary to show that there is a fixed point in these intervals?

Comment: because for a general non-linear mapping there might be multiple fixed points (non-unique solution), or no solution at all

Comment: Unfortunately I cant seem to figure this out. Am i to show that $T$ on $[h,2h]$ is a contraction?

Comment: non-linear mappings can be approximated by almost-linear mappings in sufficiently small regions, however these do not guarantee global unique solution (see previous comment)

Comment: but when proving the actual theorem (using contraction mapping), how does linearity come into play? right now for my linear ode I can guarantee that a solution exists on $[0,c]$...in the proof, what is special about linear equations that allows me to find a unique solution in $[c,2c]$.

Comment: I am sorry for asking naive questions---this is my first time being exposed to an existence theorem for ODEs

Comment: sure, i'm checking this out myself, since there is some time since studying ODEs, the point is satisfaction of the [conditiions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for a [global unique solution to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Theories_of_ODEs) using the [Banach fixed-point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

Comment: see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/an-existence-of-global-solution-of-differential-equation-of-first-order) for extending local solutions to globals ones using the Picard–Lindelöf conditions

Comment: Why does the existence of a global solution amount to showing that the  unique local solution does not blow up?

Comment: i presume (i will have to look more closely) because either it does not exist or is not unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the initial value problem for a firs order ODE
$$
y'=g(t,y),\quad y(t_0)=y_0.
$$
This is transformed into de integral equation
$$
y(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^tg(s,y(s))\,ds.
$$
If $g$ is continuous and Lipschitz in the $y$ variable, using the contraction principle, one shows that there is a unique solution on an interval $[t_0,t_1]$, $t_1>t$. The length of the interval, $t_1-t_0$, depends on $g$ **and** the initial value $y_0$. One can apply the same procedure with the initial time $t_1$ (and initial value $y(t_1)$) and extend the solution to a larger interval $[t_0,t_2]$. In general $t_2-t_1$ may be smaller that $t_1-t_2$. But if $g$ satisfies an inequality like $|g(t,y_1)-g(t,y_2)|\le M\,|y_1-y_2|$, then it is possible to show that the length of the interval in which the solution is defined is independent of the initial value. This happens in particular for linear equations, in which $g(t,y)=a(t)\,y$.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but this amounts to showing that $T$ is a contraction in $C[h,2h]$ correct? If the nonlinear ODE has $g$ satisfying Lipschitz in the secon variable, then is it not true that $|Tu-T|=|\int_{t_0}^t(g(s,u(s))-g(s,v(s)) \ ds| \leq (t-t_0)||u-v||$, and therefore a contraction, even on $[h,2h]$? So this should work in the nonlinear case as well?

Comment: ah..the condition you mentioned implies that $g(t,y)$ is Lipschitzeverywhere..a property not shared by all nonlinear such functions $g$ because the $g$ may stop being Lipschitz outside $R$..is this correct?

Comment: If $g$ is globaly Lipschitz, then the length of the interval in which the contraction principle guarantees the existence of solution does not depend on the intial value. The typical example in which this does not happen is $y'=y^2$, $y(0)=1$, whose solution $y=1/(1-t)$ is defined on $[0,1)$.