# Show that the existence of $y(x)$ of ODE follows by Peano existence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Following this question: [An existence of global solution of differential equation of first order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/an-existence-of-global-solution-of-differential-equation-of-first-order).

> Consider the IVP: assume that $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbf R\times\mathbf R^d \to\mathbf R^d$, for $x\in\mathbf R$ and $y\in\mathbf R^d$,
> $$
> y'(x)=f(x, y).
> $$
> Suppose that for any $x\in\mathbf R$ there are two continuous functions $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ and a constant $K$ so that whenever $|y|\ge K$,
> $$
> |f(x,y)|\le A(x)+B(x)|y|
> $$

Show that the existence of $y(x)$ on $\mathbf R$.

---

My idea of proof is that:
Step 1: construct $A_1(x)$ and $B_1(x)$ so that for any $x\in\mathbf R$ and $y\in\mathbf R^d$,
$$
|f(x,y)|\le A_1(x)+B_1(x)|y|
$$

Step 2: By Peano theorem of local existence, since $f(x,y)$ is continuous, then  there is a local solution.

Step 3: show that it is global if you can show that the solution does not blow up.

---

For the first step: I choose a rectangle domain $R:=\{(x,y): |x|\le L, |y|\le H\}$. Then we choose $A_1(x)=\max |f(x,y)|$ and $B_1(x)=0$ since $f$ is continuous on this bounded domain the maximal value can be attained. For $x\in R^c$, we just take $A_1(x)=A(x)$ and $B_1(x)=B(x)$.

Does it ok?

For the third step: I am stuck on how to get the upper bound on the exp. I get

$$
(|y(x)|^2)'\le 2A_1(x)|y(x)|+2B_1(x)|y(x)|^2
$$

Comment: You do not get a Lipschitz condition, you cannot apply Picard-Lindelöf for this task. Use the Peano theorem of local existence for continuous right sides. Then show a bound using Grönwall, and argue that the maximal interval of any solution can not have finite boundaries.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! Does my upper bound for $|f(x, y)|$ ok for any $x\in R$ and $y\in R^d$ by choosing $A_1$ and $B_1$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am stuck on how to apply Grönwall? I got the last display, but how to use Grönwall?

Comment: Please read the task again. The last section shows that you did not understand that the linear bound of $f$ is a given assumption. // Grönwall: Let $u$ be a solution to $u'(x)=A(x)+B(x)u(x)$, with $u(x_0)=|y_0|$, then $|y(x)|\le u(x)$ for $x\ge x_0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann No, you miss that the linear bound of $f$ is given just for $|y|\ge K$, not everywhere.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am still confused about the inequality. I obtain that $|y(x)|\le |y(x_0)|+\int_{x_0}^x (A(s)+B(s)|y(s)|)ds$. But how to get $|y(x)|\le u(x)$? Also, to use Gronwall, do we need to get form like $|y'(x)|\le \lambda(x)|y(x)|$?

Comment: Also, I try to use that $|y'(x)|\le A(x)+B(x)|y(x)|$, however, the LHS is not $(|y(x)|')$...

Comment: Then use $u(x_0)=\max(K,|y_0|)$ or even $u(x_0)=K+|y_0|$. You do not need the tightest bound, just any bound at all that is non-singular. // The proof of the Grönwall lemma is non-trivial, whatever way you package it. The careful handling of norms and division-by-zero is part of that. One way is to start with $u(x_0)>|y_0|+\epsilon$, assume that there is a cross-over point and then show that that is impossible. Other ways apply the solution formula for first-order linear DE more directly.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! Can you explain more about " Other ways apply the solution formula for first-order linear DE more directly."? But how about your previous answer: "$|y(x)|\le u(x)$? How to get that? And is this useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f$ is only continuous, one can only apply the Peano theorem to get local solutions. These need not be unique.

By the usual projective limit construction local solutions can be extended to solutions with maximal domain.

By the Grönwall theorem, the function $u$ satisfying
$$
u'(x)=\begin{cases}
A(x)+B(x)u(x)&\text{for }x> x_0\\
-A(x)-B(x)u(x)&\text{for } x<x_0
\end{cases},~~~u(x_0)=\max(K,|y_0|)
$$
is an upper bound of $|y(x)|$ for any solution of the IVP $y(x_0)=y_0$.

As this bound defines a compact set over any finite interval that a solution can only leave in $x$ direction, the domain of a maximal solution has to contain any such finite interval, thus is the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you please write more detail about how to get the bound via Grönwald inequality?